# Please reopen my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen

My question
[Is it an illusion if reheated tea burns my tongue but tastes cold?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605833/) from Jan 6 '21 has been closed on Apr 26 '21 as "Needs more focus". The question is not unfocused. It is true that the question didn't get an answer within 4 month (or even a comment), but I see no indication that rewritting the question (without performing the described simple experiment more carefully and better controlled) would change that.

(The two differences I see to questions like [Is it possible that an instant coffee 3 in 1 (or any other type of coffee) is cooling faster than tea?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541655/) or [Does tea made with boiling water cool faster than tea made with boiled (but still hot) water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476178/) is that those attracted attention immediately after being posted, and that the rate of cooling is a bit easier to measure than the difference between surface and bulk temperature.)

Answer (score 6):

(For [version 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/605833/1))You have two explicit questions. The first is in the title: *"Is it an illusion if reheated tea burns my tongue but tastes cold?"*. The second is at the very end: *"why should there be a difference in how well the oil-like substance is "mixed"?"* It seems like the post is asking about both of these at the same time without any specific focus on either.

Comment: Thanks: I get two points from your answer: After I have done the described simple experiment more carefully and better controlled, I can ask a separate question about it, if it should still show the same unexpected (for my physical intuition) outcome. The second point I got is how I can improve my current question (independent of whether it will be reopened or whether it will get an answer after being reopened).